# Azure - PowerShell how to Restore/Re-Set the variable values after reconnect

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-api-management

I am using `Azure` powershell to create an APIM management resources as below:

```
.
.
.

$apimService = New-AzApiManagement `
    -ResourceGroupName $resGroupName `
    -Location $location `
    -Name $apimServiceName `
    -Organization $apimOrganization `
    -AdminEmail $apimAdminEmail `
    -VirtualNetwork $apimVirtualNetwork `
    -VpnType "Internal" `
    -Sku "Developer"
```

But, since APIM takes a lot of time to create, the powershell terminal times out and I have to reconnect. What happens is, the variable `$apimService` is set to null after reconnecting to the terminal again.

Because of that, I cannot execute the following command:

```
.
.
.

$proxyHostnameConfig = New-AzApiManagementCustomHostnameConfiguration `
  -Hostname $gatewayHostname `
  -HostnameType Proxy `
  -PfxPath $gatewayCertPfxPath `
  -PfxPassword $certPwd


// this command complains as variable $apimService is null 
$apimService.ProxyCustomHostnameConfiguration = $proxyHostnameConfig
```

What is the best way to preserve these variable values even after a 2 hours of time? Because APIm takes nearly 1 hour of time to complete when SKU is `Developer`

Can someone please help me?

Thank you,
Best Regards

Comment: Once it's finished creating, you could use `Get-AzApiManagement` to repopulate your variable. You'll also need to do `Set-AzApiManagement` to actually apply the change. That should solve your immediate issue, but I'm curious how you're accessing Powershell that it times out and you lose the session variables?

Comment: Hi @AnthonyNorwood I am accessing the powershell from the console. When I execute the above creation command, it just keeps there, as obvious until it reates the APIM and then after some time it gives that pop window to `Reconnect` ot to `Exit`. Can you please give the full commands to persist the variable data? I am very new to powershell and struggling with its commands :)

Comment: Hi Jananath; can you be a bit more specific about this console? I'm intrigued more than anything, as I just use Powershell locally so there's no session to timeout. With regards to the commands, the Microsoft docs on [Get-AzApiManagement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/get-azapimanagement?view=azps-9.4.0) and [Set-AzApiManagement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/set-azapimanagement?view=azps-9.4.0) will be your friends here.

Comment: Hi @AnthonyNorwood, there's a default 10 minutes timeout for powershell in azure cloud. Somehow I managed to do it with a little hack, which is pressing enter before the time out and of course the resources you have given helped me a lot. Thank you man :)

Comment: You're very welcome! I'll pop my suggestion as an Answer, if you'd be so kind as to mark as an accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Once it's finished creating, you can use [Get-AzApiManagement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/get-azapimanagement?view=azps-9.4.0) to repopulate your variable.

```
$apimService = Get-AzApiManagement -Name [Name] -ResourceGroupName [RGName]
```

You'll also need to do [Set-AzApiManagement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/set-azapimanagement?view=azps-9.4.0) to actually apply the change.

```
$apimService | Set-AzApiManagement
```

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and below is the result**

I have used below powershell script to create an **API Management**

```
Connect-AzAccount
New-AzResourceGroup -Name myResourceGroup -Location WestUS
$global:Head = New-AzApiManagement -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Location "West US"-Organization "venkatapitest" -AdminEmail "v-vallepuv@microsoft.com" -Sku "Developer"
```

When i ran the above powershell commands, **API Management** got is created successfully without getting timedout error, like below.

[image]

I have tested same script in **Azure Cloud Shell**.

[image]

`$global` . This will ensure global scope which will allow you to get values in console.